# How can I bring information from ElasticSearch in batches if it is on many levels?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have info in ES. The mapping is very simple :

```
{
    "index": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "level1": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "level2": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "level3": {
                                "type": "nested",
                                "properties": {
                                    "value1": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "value2": {
                                        "type": "long"
                                    },
                                    "id": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "value3": {
                                        "type": "long"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1505476515647",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "_0IiQCPrQ1i-kDP1481y8w",
                "version": {
                    "created": "2030099"
                }
            }
        },
        "warmers": {}
    }
}
```

and when i do the query:

```
 {"query": {"terms": {"_id": [ "value51" ] }}}
```

I receive data with this structure:

```
_source (dict)
  level1 (list)
     level2 (list)
        data1 (dict)
              id
              value1
              value2
              value3
        data2 (dict)
        data3 (dict)
        ...
        data65000 (dict)
```

The problem is that 65,000 data are too many, and I run out of memory, I would like to know if _search or ElasticSearch in general has some way of bringing that information (data1,data2,data3...) in batches. Or if there is some way to make that query so that I do not run out of memory on the computer. Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the scroll API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) feature: just configure list of fields, for example:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "data1*"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
        "value51"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And then:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "data2*"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
        "value51"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But it can decrease performance because of multiple queries.